# SHA-256 written in JavaScript ends in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hash, sha256

If you look at the main function at the end of the JavaScript program, there are those variables (a, b... until h). Every variable is an array of booleans and that is important (must be an array of booleans every loop run). At a certain point the variable d is 1, because c is computed wrong earlier.

With d = 1 the line `e = add(d, temp1)` makes the function `add()` execute its second for loop in an infinite loop. I am pretty sure that the error is caused by one of the logic functions or "tool-functions" used for the main-algorithm function. I can't find the issue. Can someone help me with that?

After my JavaScript Implementation I add the Python implementation, which I used to understand how to implement the algorithm in JavaScript. The way those programs work is quite similar

SHA256 in JavaScript

```js
function SHA2(message) {

    var h = ["0x6a09e667", "0xbb67ae85", "0x3c6ef372", "0xa54ff53a", "0x510e527f", "0x9b05688c", "0x1f83d9ab", "0x5be0cd19"]
    const k = ["0x428a2f98", "0x71374491", "0xb5c0fbcf", "0xe9b5dba5", "0x3956c25b", "0x59f111f1", "0x923f82a4","0xab1c5ed5", "0xd807aa98", "0x12835b01", "0x243185be", "0x550c7dc3", "0x72be5d74","0x80deb1fe","0x9bdc06a7", "0xc19bf174", "0xe49b69c1", "0xefbe4786", "0x0fc19dc6", "0x240ca1cc", "0x2de92c6f","0x4a7484aa", "0x5cb0a9dc","0x76f988da", "0x983e5152", "0xa831c66d", "0xb00327c8", "0xbf597fc7","0xc6e00bf3", "0xd5a79147", "0x06ca6351", "0x14292967", "0x27b70a85","0x2e1b2138", "0x4d2c6dfc","0x53380d13", "0x650a7354", "0x766a0abb", "0x81c2c92e", "0x92722c85", "0xa2bfe8a1", "0xa81a664b","0xc24b8b70","0xc76c51a3", "0xd192e819", "0xd6990624", "0xf40e3585", "0x106aa070", "0x19a4c116","0x1e376c08", "0x2748774c", "0x34b0bcb5", "0x391c0cb3","0x4ed8aa4a", "0x5b9cca4f", "0x682e6ff3","0x748f82ee", "0x78a5636f", "0x84c87814", "0x8cc70208", "0x90befffa", "0xa4506ceb", "0xbef9a3f7","0xc67178f2"]

    function isTrue(x) {return x == 1}
    function if_(i, y, z) {if(isTrue(i)){return y}else{return z}}
    function and_(i, j) {return if_(i, j, 0)}
    function AND(i, j) {
        c_stop = Math.min(i.length, j.length)

        result = Array()
        for(c = 0; c<c_stop; c++) {
            result.push(and_(i[c], j[c]))
        }

        return result
    }
    function not_(i) {return if_(i, 0, 1)}
    function NOT(i) {
        result = Array()

        for(c = 0; c<i.length; c++) {
            result.push(not_(i[c]))
        }

        return result
    }
    function xor(i, j) {return if_(i, not_(j), j)}
    function XOR(i, j) {
        c_stop = Math.min(i.length, j.length)
        result = Array()

        for(c = 0; c<c_stop; c++) {
            result.push(xor(i[c], j[c]))
        }

        return result

    }
    function xorxor(i, j, l) {return xor(i, xor(j, l))}
    function XORXOR(i, j, l) {
        c_stop = Math.min(Math.min(i.length, j.length), l.length)
        result = Array()

        for(c = 0; c<c_stop; c++) {
            result.push(xorxor(i[c], j[c], l[c]))   
        }

        return result
    }

    function maj(i, j, k) {
        const arr = [i, j, k]
        const count = {}

        for(const element of arr) {
            if(count[element]) {
                count[element] += 1;
            }else {
                count[element] = 1;
            }
        }

        const keys = Array()
        const values = Array()
        for(c = 0; c<3; c++) {
            values.push(count[arr[c]])
            keys.push(arr[c])
        }

        var big = 0
        for(c = 0; c<keys.length; c++) {
            if(values[c] > values[big]) {
                big = c
            }
        }

        return keys[big]

    }

    //translating message given as string into binary sequence
    //each character is returned as 1byte
    function translate(message) {
        const chars = [...message] //returns message as char array
        var result = Array()

        for(c = 0; c <chars.length; c++) {
            var charAsBinary = ((chars[c]).charCodeAt()).toString(2)
            var binaryLength = charAsBinary.length
            for (c_ = 0; c_ <8-binaryLength; c_++) {
                charAsBinary = charAsBinary + "0"
            }
            var tempArray = [...charAsBinary]
            for(c_ = 0; c_<tempArray.length; c_++) {
                result.push(Number(tempArray[c_]))
            }
        }

        return result
    }

    //given is an array of arrays like [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [], [], ...]
    function fillZeros(bits, length=8, endian) {

        bitLength = bits.length

        if (endian == "LE") {
            for(c = bitLength; c<length; c++) {
                bits.push(0)
            }

        } else {
            toAdd = Array()

            for(c = bitLength; c<length; c++) {
                toAdd.push(0)
            }
            Array.prototype.unshift.apply(bits, toAdd)
        }

        return bits
    }

    function chunker(bits, chunk_length=8) {
        chunked = Array()

        for (let i = 0; i < bits.length; i += chunk_length) {
            const chunk = bits.slice(i, i + chunk_length);
            chunked.push(chunk)
        }

        return chunked

    }

    function binaryToHex(value) {
        var result = chunker(value, 4)
        var returning = ""

        for(c = 0; c<result.length; c++) {
            returning = returning + ((parseInt(result[c], 2)).toString(16))
        }

        return returning
    }

    function initializer(values) {

        result = Array()

        for(c = 0; c<values.length; c++) {
            var toPush = [...parseInt(values[c], 16).toString(2)].map(Number)

            while(toPush.length != 32) {
                toPush.unshift(0)
            }

            result.push(toPush)
        }



        return result
    }

    function preprocessMessage(message) {
        bits = translate(message)
        bits_length = bits.length
        bits_length_as_binary = fillZeros([...bits_length.toString(2)].map(Number), 64, "BE")

        if(bits_length < 448) {
            bits.push(Number(1))
            bits = fillZeros(bits, 448, "LE")
            bits.push.apply(bits, bits_length_as_binary)
            return [bits]
        }else if(448 <= bits_length <= 512) {
            bits.push(Number(1))
            bits = fillZeros(bits, 1024, "LE")
            bits.splice(-64, 64)
            bits.push.apply(bits, bits_length_as_binary)
            return chunker(bits, 512)
        }else {
            bits.push(Number(1))
            while(bits.length % 512 != 0) {
                bits.push(Number(0))
            }
            bits.splice(-64, 64)
            bits.push.apply(bits, bits_length_as_binary)
            return chunker(bits, 512)
        }
    }

    function rotr(x, n) {
        for(c = 0; c<n; c++) {
            x.unshift(x.pop());
        }
        return x
    }
      
    function shr(x, n) {
        for(c = 0; c<n; c++) {
            x.pop()
            x.unshift(0)
        }
        return x
    }

    function add(i, j) {

        length = i.length

        sums = Array()

        for(c = 0; c<length; c++) {
            sums.push(c)
        }

        c = 0
        for(x = length-1; x != 0-1; x--) {
            sums[x] = xorxor(i[x], j[x], c)
            c = maj(i[x], j[x], c)
        }
        return sums
    }

    function main(message) {
        k_ = initializer(k)

        hConstants = initializer(h)
        h0 = hConstants[0]
        h1 = hConstants[1]
        h2 = hConstants[2]
        h3 = hConstants[3]
        h4 = hConstants[4]
        h5 = hConstants[5]
        h6 = hConstants[6]
        h7 = hConstants[7]


        console.log("h0: ", h0)
        console.log("h1: ", h1)
        console.log("h2: ", h2)
        console.log("h3: ", h3)
        console.log("h4: ", h4)
        console.log("h5: ", h5)
        console.log("h6: ", h6)
        console.log("h7: ", h7)

        chunks = preprocessMessage(message)



        for(x = 0; x<chunks.length; x++) {
            w = chunker(chunks[x], 32)

            for(m = 0; m != 48; m++) {
                w.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
            }

            for(y = 16; y<64; y++) {

                sh1 = y-15
                sh2 = y-2

                add1 = y-16
                add2 = y-7

                s0 = XORXOR(rotr(w[sh1], 7), rotr(w[sh1], 18), shr(w[sh1], 3))
                s1 = XORXOR(rotr(w[sh2], 17), rotr(w[sh2], 19), shr(w[sh2], 10))
                w[y] = add(add(add(w[add1], s0), w[add2]), s1) //possibly error w[i-7] maybe i-17 was meant...
            }

            a = h0
            b = h1
            c = h2
            d = h3
            e = h4
            f = h5
            g = h6
            h = h7

            for(z = 0; z<64; z++) {
                S1 = XORXOR(rotr(e, 6), rotr(e, 11), rotr(e, 25))
                ch = XOR(AND(e, f), AND(NOT(e), g))
                temp1 = add(add(add(add(h, S1), ch), k_[z]), w[z])
                S0 = XORXOR(rotr(a, 2), rotr(a, 13), rotr(a, 22))
                m = XORXOR(AND(a, b), AND(a, c), AND(b, c))
                temp2 = add(S0, m)

                h = g
                g = f
                f = e

                e = add(d, temp1)
                d = c
                c = b
                b = a
                a = add(temp1, temp2)
            }

            h0 = add(h0, a)
            h1 = add(h1, b)
            h2 = add(h2, c)
            h3 = add(h3, d)
            h4 = add(h4, e)
            h5 = add(h5, f)
            h6 = add(h6, g)
            h7 = add(h7, h)
        }

        digest = ""

        digest = digest + binaryToHex(h0)
        digest = digest + binaryToHex(h1)
        digest = digest + binaryToHex(h2)
        digest = digest + binaryToHex(h3)
        digest = digest + binaryToHex(h4)
        digest = digest + binaryToHex(h5)
        digest = digest + binaryToHex(h6)
        digest = digest + binaryToHex(h7)

        return digest


    }

    return main(message)

}

SHA2("test")
```

SHA256 in Python:

```py
def translate(message):
    charcodes = [ord(c) for c in message]
    bytes = []
    for char in charcodes:
        bytes.append(bin(char)[2:].zfill(8))
    bits = []
    for byte in bytes:
        for bit in byte:
            bits.append(int(bit))
    return bits



def b2Tob16(value):
  value = "".join([str(x) for x in value])
  binaries = []
  for d in range(0, len(value), 4):
    binaries.append("0b" + value[d:d+4])
  hexes = ""
  for b in binaries:
    hexes += hex(int(b ,2))[2:]
  return hexes



def fillZeros(bits, length=8, endian="LE"):
    l = len(bits)
    if endian == "LE":
        for i in range(l, length):
            bits.append(0) 
    else: 
        while l < length:
            bits.insert(0, 0) 
            l = len(bits)
    return bits



def chunker(bits, chunk_length=8):
    chunked = []
    for b in range(0, len(bits), chunk_length):
        chunked.append(bits[b:b+chunk_length])
    return chunked

h = ["0x6a09e667", "0xbb67ae85", "0x3c6ef372", "0xa54ff53a", "0x510e527f", "0x9b05688c", "0x1f83d9ab", "0x5be0cd19"]

k = [
"0x428a2f98", "0x71374491", "0xb5c0fbcf", "0xe9b5dba5", "0x3956c25b", "0x59f111f1", "0x923f82a4","0xab1c5ed5", "0xd807aa98", "0x12835b01", "0x243185be", "0x550c7dc3", "0x72be5d74",
"0x80deb1fe","0x9bdc06a7", "0xc19bf174", "0xe49b69c1", "0xefbe4786", "0x0fc19dc6", "0x240ca1cc", "0x2de92c6f","0x4a7484aa", "0x5cb0a9dc",
"0x76f988da", "0x983e5152", "0xa831c66d", "0xb00327c8", "0xbf597fc7","0xc6e00bf3", "0xd5a79147", "0x06ca6351", "0x14292967", "0x27b70a85",
"0x2e1b2138", "0x4d2c6dfc","0x53380d13", "0x650a7354", "0x766a0abb", "0x81c2c92e", "0x92722c85", "0xa2bfe8a1", "0xa81a664b","0xc24b8b70",
"0xc76c51a3", "0xd192e819", "0xd6990624", "0xf40e3585", "0x106aa070", "0x19a4c116","0x1e376c08", "0x2748774c", "0x34b0bcb5", "0x391c0cb3",
"0x4ed8aa4a", "0x5b9cca4f", "0x682e6ff3","0x748f82ee", "0x78a5636f", "0x84c87814", "0x8cc70208", "0x90befffa", "0xa4506ceb", "0xbef9a3f7","0xc67178f2"]


def initializer(values):
    binaries = [bin(int(v, 16))[2:] for v in values]

    words = []
    for binary in binaries:
        word = []
        for b in binary:
            word.append(int(b))
        words.append(fillZeros(word, 32, "BE"))
    return words



def preprocessMessage(message):
    bits = translate(message)
    length = len(bits)
    message_len = [int(b) for b in bin(length)[2:].zfill(64)]
    if length < 448:
        bits.append(1)
        bits = fillZeros(bits, 448, "LE")
        bits = bits + message_len
        return [bits]
    elif 448 <= length <= 512:
        bits.append(1)
        bits = fillZeros(bits, 1024, "LE")
        bits[-64:] = message_len
        return chunker(bits, 512)
    else:
        bits.append(1)
        while len(bits) % 512 != 0:
            bits.append(0)
        bits[-64:] = message_len
    return chunker(bits, 512)




def isTrue(x): return x == 1

def if_(i, y, z): return y if isTrue(i) else z

def and_(i, j): return if_(i, j, 0)
def AND(i, j): return [and_(ia, ja) for ia, ja in zip(i,j)] 

def not_(i): return if_(i, 0, 1)
def NOT(i): return [not_(x) for x in i]

def xor(i, j): return if_(i, not_(j), j)
def XOR(i, j): return [xor(ia, ja) for ia, ja in zip(i, j)]

def xorxor(i, j, l): return xor(i, xor(j, l))
def XORXOR(i, j, l): return [xorxor(ia, ja, la) for ia, ja, la, in zip(i, j, l)]

def maj(i,j,k): return max([i,j], key=[i,j,k].count)


def rotr(x, n): return x[-n:] + x[:-n]
def shr(x, n): return n * [0] + x[:-n]

def add(i, j):
  length = len(i)
  sums = list(range(length))
  c = 0
  # going from length-1 to -1 (which means loop ends by 0) and last -1 means decrement x
  for x in range(length-1,-1,-1):
    sums[x] = xorxor(i[x], j[x], c)
    c = maj(i[x], j[x], c)
  return sums


def sha256(message, k=k, h=h, ): 
    k = initializer(k)
    h0, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7 = initializer(h)
    chunks = preprocessMessage(message)

    for chunk in chunks:

        w = chunker(chunk, 32)

        for _ in range(48):
            w.append(32 * [0])



        for i in range(16, 64):

            sh1 = i-15
            sh2 = i-2

            add1 = i-16
            add2 = i-7

            s0 = XORXOR(rotr(w[i-15], 7), rotr(w[i-15], 18), shr(w[i-15], 3)) 
            s1 = XORXOR(rotr(w[i-2], 17), rotr(w[i-2], 19), shr(w[i-2], 10))
            w[i] = add(add(add(w[i-16], s0), w[i-7]), s1) #possibly error w[i-7] maybe i-17

        a = h0
        b = h1
        c = h2
        d = h3
        e = h4
        f = h5
        g = h6
        h = h7
        for j in range(64):
            S1 = XORXOR(rotr(e, 6), rotr(e, 11), rotr(e, 25) )
            ch = XOR(AND(e, f), AND(NOT(e), g))
            temp1 = add(add(add(add(h, S1), ch), k[j]), w[j])
            S0 = XORXOR(rotr(a, 2), rotr(a, 13), rotr(a, 22))
            m = XORXOR(AND(a, b), AND(a, c), AND(b, c))
            temp2 = add(S0, m)
            h = g
            g = f
            f = e
            e = add(d, temp1)
            d = c
            c = b
            b = a
            a = add(temp1, temp2)
        h0 = add(h0, a)
        h1 = add(h1, b)
        h2 = add(h2, c)
        h3 = add(h3, d)
        h4 = add(h4, e)
        h5 = add(h5, f)
        h6 = add(h6, g)
        h7 = add(h7, h)
    digest = ""
    for val in [h0, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7]:
        digest += b2Tob16(val)
    return digest


sha256("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask for it but this is already supported by modern browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest

```js
const text = 'test';

async function digestMessage(message) {
  const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(message); // encode as (utf-8) Uint8Array
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgUint8); // hash the message
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)); // convert buffer to byte array
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''); // convert bytes to hex string
  return hashHex;
}

digestMessage(text)
  .then(digestHex => console.log(digestHex));
```

Comment: Yes. I would never start to write an own implementation if i wouldn't need to. My task is to create a visualization of the sha2 algorithm trough a website plugin. I got this wonderful python code... but the java script version isn't working..